# Prove that the cellularity of $X$ is less than or equal to the density of $X$

Tags: general-topology

> The **cellularity** of $X$ is $c(X) = \sup\{|O|\}$ where $O$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint open sets. The **density** of $X$ is $d(X) = \min\{|D|: \overline{D} = X\}$. Show that $c(X) \leq d(X)$.

I personally have no idea how to show this. Otherwise, I would attempt to show some work here. Any suggestions on what to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that for every dense set $D$ and a collection of pairwise disjoint open sets $O$ then $|O| \le |D|$.

We will use the next fact about dense sets and open sets: let $A$ be a dense set and let $U$ be an open set then $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

Now we construct a function $f:O \to D$:
Let $U \in O$ abd choose $x_U \in U \cap D$ (exist as $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$ ) and define  $f(U)=x_U$.

Thus $f$ is injective because the sets in $O$ are disjoint and for every $U \in O$, $f(U) \in U$. And thus $|O| \le |D|$